# how to Send an EMail with attachement in custom module

Tags: magento-1.8, php-5.4, phpstorm

I'm new to magento I created custom module for customer quote request, In that after filling quote request we need to send an email. So that I wrote fallowing code.

I add the **Add Quote button** in below form.

```
design->frontentd->Test->default->template->catalog->product->list.phtml

<p><button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Quote') ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Quote') ?></span></span></button></p>
```

when customer click I navigate the `design->frontend->Test->default->template->checkout->cart->test.phtml` file, this design code below.

```
<form action="<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkout/quote/sendMail') ?>" method="post">

    <div style="border-color: red;">
        <div class="page-title">
            <h1>Request For Quote</h1>
        <div class="fieldset">
            <h2 class="legend">RFQ Requirements</h2>
           <table>
               <tr>
                   <td>
                        Company Name :
                   </td>
                   <td>
                       <input style="font-size:14px;" name="company" value="" class="input-text" type="text" size="29"/>
                   </td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                   <td>
                        Contact Name :
                   </td>
                   <td>
                       <input style="font-size:14px;" name="contact_name" value="" class="input-text" type="text" size="29"/>
                   </td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                   <td>
                        Email :
                   </td>
                   <td>
                       <input style="font-size:14px;" name="email" value="" class="input-text" type="text" size="29"/>
                   </td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                   <td>
                        Phone Number :
                   </td>
                   <td>
                       <input style="font-size:14px;" name="phone" value="" class="input-text" type="text" size="29"/>
                   </td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                   <td>
                        Project Title :
                   </td>
                   <td>
                       <input style="font-size:14px;" name="project_title" value="" class="input-text" type="text" size="29"/>
                   </td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                   <td>
                        Quote Needed By :
                   </td>
                   <td>
                       <input style="font-size:14px;" name="date" value="" class="input-text" type="text" size="29"/>
                   </td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                   <td>
                        Project Budget Status :
                   </td>
                   <td>
                       <input style="font-size:14px;" name="budget_status" value="" class="input-text" type="text" size="29"/>
                   </td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                   <td>
                        Brief Overview :
                   </td>
                   <td>
                       <textarea name="overview" id="overview" title="Brief Overview" class="input-text required-entry" style="font-size:14px;" name="overview" cols="55" rows="10" id="project_overview"></textarea>
                   </td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                   <td colspan="2" align="right">
                       <p class="required">* Required Fields</p>
                       <button type="submit" title="Submit" class="button"><span><span>Send Request</span></span></button>
                   </td>
               </tr>
           </table>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

In `app\code\core\Mage\Checkout\controllers` I created `QuoteController.php` this code is below.

```
<?php

class Mage_Checkout_QuoteController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
    function indexAction()
    {
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->_initLayoutMessages('customer/session');
        $this->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->setTitle($this->__('Request for Quote'));
        $this->renderLayout();
        Mage::log("Request for quote");
    }

    public function sendMailAction()
    {
        //send Mail
        Mage::log("Send Mail");
       $to="dotnet@gmail.com";
        $com_name = $_POST['company'];
        $contact_name = $_POST['contact_name'];
        $pro_title = $_POST['project_title'];
        $phone_tel = $_POST['phone'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $date = $_POST['date'];
        $bud_status = $_POST['budget_status'];
        $comment = $_POST['overview'];

               $mime_boundary="==Multipart_Boundary_x".md5(mt_rand())."x";

               $headers = "From:$email\r\n" .
                   "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n" .
                   "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\r\n" .
                   " boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\"";

               $subjects = "Request For Quote " . "From : $email";

               $subject="Details From : $subjects";

               $message="Company Name: $com_name\r\n".
                   "Contact Name:  $contact_name\r\n".
                   "Mobile No.: $phone_tel\r\n".
                   "Email: $email\r\n".
                   "Project Title: $pro_title\r\n " .
                   "Estimated Date: $date\r\n " .
                   "Budget Status: $bud_status\r\n " .
                   "Comments : $comment\r\n";


               $message = "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\r\n\r\n" .
                   "--{$mime_boundary}\r\n" .
                   "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\r\n" .
                   "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n\r\n" .
                   $message . "\r\n\r\n";

               $message.="--{$mime_boundary}--\n";

               @mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

        Mage::log("Send Mail End");

    }

}
```

when customer hit the **Send Request** button I call the `sendMailAction()` action but the mail is not sending.

even though I configure the mail settings in admin panel also but it's not sending mail.

can anyone tell me where I went wrong & tell me the how to attach if any files is there?

Answer (score 1):

Hello  you can use the below code for attachment.

you can use zend and this code is tested.

**Source :** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20904249/how-to-attach-a-csv-file-to-php-email-code-running-from-the-magento-root/20944539#20944539

```
require 'app/Mage.php';
umask( 0 );
Mage :: app( "default" );
$mail = new Zend_Mail();
$mail->setType(Zend_Mime::MULTIPART_RELATED);
$mail->setBodyHtml($html_body);
$mail->setFrom('support@example.com', 'Example');
$mail->addTo('dev.amitbera@gmail.com', 'Amit');
$mail->setSubject('Sending email using Zend Framework');
$dir = Mage::getBaseDir();
$path = $dir.DS.'var'.DS.'docs'.DS.'test.csv';
$file = $mail->createAttachment(file_get_contents($path));
$file ->type        = 'text/csv';
$file ->disposition = Zend_Mime::DISPOSITION_INLINE;
$file ->encoding    = Zend_Mime::ENCODING_BASE64;
$file ->filename    = 'test.csv';
$mail->send();



<?php
    $mail = new Zend_Mail();
    $mail->setType(Zend_Mime::MULTIPART_RELATED);
    $mail->setBodyHtml($html_body);
    $mail->setFrom('support@example.com', 'Example');
    $mail->addTo('dev.amitbera@gmail.com', 'Amit');
    $mail->setSubject('Sending email using Zend Framework');
    $dir = Mage::getBaseDir();
    $path = $dir.DS.'var'.DS.'docs'.DS.'test.csv';
    $file = $mail->createAttachment(file_get_contents($path));
    $file ->type        = 'text/csv';
    $file ->disposition = Zend_Mime::DISPOSITION_INLINE;
    $file ->encoding    = Zend_Mime::ENCODING_BASE64;
    $file ->filename    = 'test.csv';
    $mail->send();
?>
```

Comment: it's not working for me.

Comment: Try setting the $file->disposition to Zend_Mime::DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT